# Shotwell event name in folder name?

Tags: shotwell

I use the following directory structure in my Pictures folder:

```
~/Pictures/2013/20130102_Event_name
```

This way, I can easily browse all photos from 2013 without going too many levels of subfolders in. Furthermore, each event has a short name associated with it acting as a reminder what happened. So far, Shotwell can handle the date format but I don't see a way to include the event name. Has anyone else faced a similar challenge? Is there a way to extend the directory structure Shotwell understands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shotwell cannot do this today; the ticket to add this feature is [here](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/3549).

Normally for feature requests I'd say "we accept patches" but here I have to admit this would be a really tricky one to implement.

That said, if you enable file monitoring in the prefs, Shotwell will recognize changes you manually make to the directory structure (i.e. in the terminal, Nautilus, etc.)  Not the best solution, but that's the only real suggestion I can give you today.